# PySide align text in a table cells?

Tags: python, pyside, qtablewidget

I have a QTable widget made in QTDesigner. In my code I setup properties of the table but I cant get text alignment working:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(myClass, self).__init__()
    # SETUP UI
    self.setupUi(self)
    # Table setup
    self.myTable.verticalHeader().hide()  # Hide row numbers        
    self.myTable.setColumnCount(4)
    self.myTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
    self.myTable.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
    # This code does not work:
    # self.myTable.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the alignment of each item using the QTableWidgetItem's `setTextAlignment()` method:

```
item = self.myTable.item(i, j)
item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

But if you want to change the alignment to all the items you must use a delegate:

```
class AlignDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

class MyClass(your_widget, your_design)
    def __init__(self):
        super(myClass, self).__init__()
        # SETUP UI
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Table setup
        self.myTable.verticalHeader().hide()  # Hide row numbers        
        self.myTable.setColumnCount(4)
        self.myTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
        self.myTable.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.myTable.setItemDelegate(AlignDelegate())
```

Comment: My table changes dynamically (i add and delete rows after the script was initialized) so I need to set the alignment of all items(cells).

But this: self.myTable.setItemDelegate(AlignDelegate())
does not work also.

`self.myTable.setItemDelegate(AlignDelegate())
AttributeError: type object 'PySide.QtCore.Qt' has no attribute 'AlignDelegate'`

Comment: @kiryha then the second option is the one for your case. If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct please.

Comment: Cant get the second option to work also.
`NameError: global name 'AlignDelegate' is not defined`

I have try `Qt.AlignDelegate()`- see previous answer and `AlignDelegate()` as well.

Comment: @kiryha Did you add the class I created and which is in the example?

Comment: Ah, my fault, miss this! Thank you, sir, now its working!

Is this the only way to set the alignment of all items in the QTableWidget? Looks like an overcomplicated solution. If there a way to do it in QT designer for example?

Comment: No, there is no such possibility for all items. This task is simple, perhaps for being a beginner think that. the delegates are the qt view class.